# Using sentence transformers with limited access to internet

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, sentence-transformers

I have access to the latest packages but I cannot access internet from my python enviroment.

Package versions that I have are as below

```
huggingface-hub-0.4.0 sacremoses-0.0.47 tokenizers-0.10.3 transformers-4.15.0
sentence-transformers-2.1.0 sentencepiece-0.1.96 torchvision-0.11.2

print (torch.__version__)
1.10.1+cu102
```

I went to the [location](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1/tree/main) and copied all the files in a folder

```
os.listdir('multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1_Jan2022/')

['config_sentence_transformers.json',
 'config.json',
 'gitattributes',
 'modules.json',
 'data_config.json',
 'sentence_bert_config.json',
 'README.md',
 'special_tokens_map.json',
 'tokenizer_config.json',
 'train_script.py',
 'vocab.txt',
 'tokenizer.json',
 '1_Pooling',
 '.ipynb_checkpoints',
 '9e1e76b7a067f72e49c7f571cd8e811f7a1567bec49f17e5eaaea899e7bc2c9e']
```

Then I went to the [url](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1) and tried to execute the code listed there

But I get below error

```
model = SentenceTransformer('multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1_Jan2022/')

OSError: Error no file named ['pytorch_model.bin', 'tf_model.h5', 'model.ckpt.index', 'flax_model.msgpack'] found in directory multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1_Jan2022/ or `from_tf` and `from_flax` set to False.
```

Where could I get those 4 files (`'pytorch_model.bin', 'tf_model.h5', 'model.ckpt.index', 'flax_model.msgpack'`) or what else do I need to change? These files are not available at the first URL mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the things you mentioned, I checked the source code of `sentence-transformers` on Google Colab. After running the model and getting the files, I check the directory and I saw the `pytorch_model.bin` there.

[image: download directory]

And according to `sentence-transformers` code:
[Link](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/2158fff3aa96651b10fe367c41fdd5008a33c5c6/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py#L80)

[image: code]

the `flax_model.msgpack` , `rust_model.ot`, `tf_model.h5` are getting ignored when the it is trying to download.

and these are the files that it downloads :

```
['1_Pooling', 'config_sentence_transformers.json', 'tokenizer.json', 'tokenizer_config.json', 'modules.json', 'sentence_bert_config.json', 'pytorch_model.bin', 'special_tokens_map.json', 'config.json', 'train_script.py', 'data_config.json', 'README.md', '.gitattributes', 'vocab.txt']
```

The only thing that you have to have to load the model is `pytorch_model.bin` file. I tested with copying the modules to another directory and it worked. And according to your question, you haven't downloaded this file, so that is the problem.

All in all, you should download the model using its command and then move the files to another directory and initialize the `SentenceTransformer` class with that dir.

I wish it would be helpful.

Comment: I checked https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/multi-qa-mpnet-base-dot-v1 again and noticed that `pytorch_model.bin
` gets downloaded as `9e1e76b7a067f72e49c7f571cd8e811f7a1567bec49f17e5eaaea899e7bc2c9e`...should I just manually change it's name?

Comment: the manual name change seems to work! let me do some more testing and then I will accept your answer

Comment: @user2543622 Great :D

Comment: where is the documentation that says `the flax_model.msgpack , rust_model.ot, tf_model.h5 are getting ignored when the model is trying to download.`

Comment: @user2543622 if you check the picture in my answer, you will see the code ignoring these files. The code is from ```sentence_transformer ``` source code.

Comment: @user2543622 I added the link in the answer

Comment: thanks. Could you explain how did you find that page?

Comment: @user2543622 search in google ```github sentence_transformer``` you will find it

Comment: @user2543622 That would be great if you accept my answer.

Comment: could you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70791672/huggingface-transformers-runtimeerror-no-module-named-tensorflow-python-keras? thanks