# huggingface transformers RuntimeError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor'

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am looking at this [workbook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/course/chapter2/section4_pt.ipynb) which comes from [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter2/2?fw=pt) course. I dont have internet access from my python environment but I could download files and save them in python environment. I copied all file from this [folder](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased/tree/main) and saved it in the folder `bert-base-uncased/`. I renamed some of the files to match what is in the above folder

I have below packages

```
tensorflow.__version__
'2.2.0'

keras.__version__
'2.4.3'
```

Then I installed transformers

```
!pip install datasets transformers[sentencepiece]
checkpoint = "bert-base-uncased/"
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification



Successfully installed datasets-1.17.0 dill-0.3.4 fsspec-2022.1.0 huggingface-hub-0.4.0 multiprocess-0.70.12.2 pyarrow-6.0.1 sacremoses-0.0.47 sentencepiece-0.1.96 tokenizers-0.10.3 transformers-4.15.0 xxhash-2.0.2
```

all the files are available

```
#files from https://huggingface.co/bert-base-uncased/tree/main
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
os.listdir('bert-base-uncased/')

['gitattributes',
 'vocab.txt',
 'tokenizer_config.json',
 'tokenizer.json',
 'README.md',
 '.dominokeep',
 'config.json',
 'tf_model.h5',
 'flax_model.msgpack',
 'rust_model.ot',
 'pytorch_model.bin']
```

But I still get the below error. I don't get this error when I run the same code using google colab

```
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased/', num_labels=2)

print ("----------------")
print (type(model))
print ("----------------")

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.bert.modeling_tf_bert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.keras_tensor'
```

Answer (score 3):

To replicate Your issue I install TensorFlow version 2.2.0.
Then I tried to import problematic module:
`from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import keras_tensor`

Yield `importError`.

**Meaning, that TensorFlow version 2.2.0 doesn't have module keras_tensor required by transformer.**

Then I updated TensorFlow to version 2.7.0 and try to import keras_tensor module again and everything worked.

Updating TensorFlow to newer version should solve Your issue.

**EDIT**
Digging a bit for lowest working version of TensorFlow I get to [setup.py](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/6ac77534bfe97c00e0127bb4fc846ae0faf1c9c5/setup.py#L148) of Transformers.
Version requirements for TensorFlow is >= 2.3.0.