# Error while loading a sentence transformer model

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, sentence-transformers

I'm trying to load transformer model from SentenceTransformer. Below is the code

```
# Now we create a SentenceTransformer model from scratch

word_emb = models.Transformer('paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2')
pooling = models.Pooling(word_emb.get_word_embedding_dimension())
model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_emb, pooling])
```

Below is the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2948\3254427654.py in <module>
      1 # Now we create a SentenceTransformer model from scratch
----> 2 word_emb = models.Transformer('paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2')
      3 pooling = models.Pooling(word_emb.get_word_embedding_dimension())
      4 model = SentenceTransformer(modules=[word_emb, pooling])

~\miniconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\models\Transformer.py in __init__(self, model_name_or_path, max_seq_length, model_args, cache_dir, tokenizer_args, do_lower_case, tokenizer_name_or_path)
     27 
     28         config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, **model_args, cache_dir=cache_dir)
---> 29         self._load_model(model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir)
     30 
     31         self.tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(tokenizer_name_or_path if tokenizer_name_or_path is not None else model_name_or_path, cache_dir=cache_dir, **tokenizer_args)

~\miniconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\models\Transformer.py in _load_model(self, model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir)
     47             self._load_t5_model(model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir)
     48         else:
---> 49             self.auto_model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, config=config, cache_dir=cache_dir)
     50 
     51     def _load_t5_model(self, model_name_or_path, config, cache_dir):

~\miniconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\auto\auto_factory.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    445         elif type(config) in cls._model_mapping.keys():
    446             model_class = _get_model_class(config, cls._model_mapping)
--> 447             return model_class.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, config=config, **kwargs)
    448         raise ValueError(
    449             f"Unrecognized configuration class {config.__class__} for this kind of AutoModel: {cls.__name__}.\n"

~\miniconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
   1310                 elif os.path.join(pretrained_model_name_or_path, FLAX_WEIGHTS_NAME):
   1311                     raise EnvironmentError(
-> 1312                         f"Error no file named {WEIGHTS_NAME} found in directory {pretrained_model_name_or_path} but "
   1313                         "there is a file for Flax weights. Use `from_flax=True` to load this model from those "
   1314                         "weights."

OSError: Error no file named pytorch_model.bin found in directory paraphrase-mpnet-base-v2 but there is a file for Flax weights. Use `from_flax=True` to load this model from those weights.
```

I'm using below versions

```
transformers==4.16.2
torch==1.11.0+cu113
torchaudio==0.11.0+cu113
torchvision==0.12.0+cu113
sentence-transformers==2.2.0
faiss-cpu==1.7.2
sentencepiece==0.1.96
```

It's been 2 months i ran this. All of a sudden, it's returning an error. I'm using FAISS-CPU as well.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that "I can't find the weights of the model you are trying to load."

Based on the error trace, I guess you are using `models` object from Sentence-Transformers library (correct me if I am wrong). One thing to note is that Sentence-Transformers only has the following paraphrase models as its [pretrained models](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html#model-overview):

- paraphrase-multilingual-mpnet-base-v2
- paraphrase-albert-small-v2
- paraphrase-multilingual-MiniLM-L12-v2
- paraphrase-MiniLM-L3-v2
  hence the one you wanted to load is not one of Sentence-Transformers pretrained models.

That brings me to think that you are trying to load a model from your local machine.
I would suggest you to create a Sentence-Transformers model like this:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model_path_or_name = "path/to/model" # A folder that contains model config files, including pytorch_model.bin
model = SentenceTransformer(model_path_or_name)
```

There was also a possibility that the `pytorch_model.bin` file was downloaded with another filename, as mentioned in the [SO thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716702/using-sentence-transformers-with-limited-access-to-internet).

Let me know if this solves your problem. Cheers.